# Any widget to close questions as off-topic in one click from questions list?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, moderator-tools, off-topic, addon

I am moderating a site [overflown by off-topic questions sent to us by the wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385509/please-reword-the-ask-question-wizards-intro-for-software-recommendations).

80% of the questions can be recognized as totally off-topic by just looking at the questions list.

**Problem**: I still need 4 clicks to close each one, which takes time, especially on a slow connection.

**Question**: Is there a sort a browser add-on or Greasemonkey script that would allow me to close as off-topic in one click? Is there is none, I am tempted to write one, but I would like to check before.

[image]

*Of course, such a tool should be used very responsibly, and on the slightest doubt the question should be opened and read in details.*

*Please note that this is intended as a stop-gap measure, and I don't intend to use it after the wizard gets fixed (but zero acknowledgement of the problem by SE staff so far, so it might take time).*

Answer (score 7):

It's not doing *entirely* what you want, but I've written a script ['Saviour' of Lost Souls](https://stackapps.com/q/8122/34061), originally made for blatantly off-topic questions here on Meta Stack Exchange, posted users who didn't have a clue what Meta was about. It leaves a welcoming comment as well, and if you have enough reputation, it even votes to delete. (As a ♦ moderator, such a vote would immediately delete the question.)

Later we recognized the script would be useful [on other sites too](https://stackapps.com/a/8185/34061), and it leaves a comment customized for Software Recommendations (you might have seen some of those already).

> Hi [AUTHOR], welcome to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)! This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within [the scope defined on meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and in the [help center](/help/on-topic). If you think you can edit it to become on-topic, please have a look at the [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377).

This script works on the question *detail* page, not on the list, because that's rather dangerous (even though you could undelete and reopen the question if you made a mistake). Also, it's two clicks: you get a popup asking to confirm your action. I can try to modify it to work on the list pages as well.

You can install it from [this direct link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/saviour-of-lost-souls/saviour-of-lost-souls.user.js).

[image]

Comment: Interesting! It is 1 click less than the standard method. I could probably be modified for faster operation.

Comment: Two clicks less, I guess (vs. close link -> off-topic -> off-topic reason -> Vote to Close button)? Deleting the question would cost you another two clicks, and commenting even more.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Glorfindel – I'll give that a look this weekend (pointer: I'm another mod from SR). And thanks also for your help directly on our site, saw a lot of your "OT comments" and wish you soon reach the rep required to directly close-vote!

Comment: Boom-chak, boom-chak, boom-chak… Yeah, works great, thanks once more! Next step would be to wed it with AutoReviewComments *LOL* … OK, going to make more boom-chak #D